# prove that $s_k>0$ for infintely many $k$ and $s_k<0$ for infintely many $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is given that the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent and $\sum a_n=0$ .Denote by $s_k$ the partial sum $\sum _{n=1}^k a_n$.

Then prove that

> $s_k>0$  for infintely many $k$ and $s_k<0$  for infintely many $k$

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $s_k > 0$ for only finitely many $k$ and prove that the series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2):

The result is false as stated. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $a_{2n-1}=\frac1n$ and $a_{2n}=-\frac1n$, so that

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n=1-1+\frac12-\frac12+\frac13-\frac13+\ldots\;.$$

Then for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have $s_{2n-1}=a_{2n-1}=\frac1n$ and $s_{2n}=0$, so $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n=0$. Thus, the series is convergent but not absolutely convergent, yet there are no negative partial sums.